# Programming with no dependencies

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc

I'm trying to make a PE ([Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) which will work with Windows XP+ and which has no dependencies.

I found this guide quite interesting http://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>

extern "C" int __cdecl __purecall(void)
{
    return 0;
}

extern "C" int __cdecl main();

extern "C" int __cdecl mainCRTStartup( void )
{
    int mainret;

    mainret = main();

    ExitProcess(mainret);
}
```

And I compile it with

```
g++ -Wall -o2 -s -nodefaultlibs main.cpp -o test.exe
```

And it's giving me a bunch of errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIFoD.png

```
C:\Users\Main.cpp\Desktop\crt>g++ -Wall -o2 -s -nodefaultlibs  -lkernel32 main.cpp -o test.exe
C:\Users\Main.cpp\AppData\Local\Temp\cczgOKUx.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x280): first defined here
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `__dyn_tls_init_callback'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `_fpreset'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `_CRT_glob'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `__getmainargs'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `_CRT_fmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `_imp___iob'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `_fmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `_setmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `_CRT_fmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `_setmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `_CRT_fmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `_setmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `__p__fmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `_fmode'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `_pei386_runtime_relocator'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `__main'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `__p__environ'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `_cexit'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `signal'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `signal'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `signal'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x217): undefined reference to `signal'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `signal'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x250): more undefined references to `signal' follow
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x266): undefined reference to `_fpreset'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `_imp____set_app_type'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `_imp____set_app_type'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2c1): undefined reference to `_imp__atexit'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2d1): undefined reference to `_imp___onexit'
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../crt2.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I understood, my mainCRTStartup is interfering with another mainCRTStartup which my compiler is adding.

I'm using TDM-GCC on Windows.

After the suggestion to use `-nostdlib` instead of `-nodefaultlibs` I'm getting much less errors.

The ones I currently have are

```
C:\Users\Main.cpp\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMYa3VN.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `__main'
C:\Users\Main.cpp\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMYa3VN.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `ExitProcess@4'
```

Comment: That catch22 tutorial is for Visual Studio. For `g++`, the procedure is different; this makes sense, because you are 'hacking away' the standard library of the used compiler.

Comment: It seems you also need to use `nostdlib` instead of `nodefaultlibs`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119520/g-static-initialization-and-nostdlib

Comment: With `-nostdlib` the huge list of errors disappeared!

Comment: It is nicer to add a textual error message than a picture that is hard to read with transparency.

Comment: Updated, I've also left the link to the image.

Comment: I'm including `kernel32.lib` with `-lkernel32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC use some internal subroutines, contained in `libgcc.a`, that cannot be excluded.
See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options:

> One of the standard libraries bypassed by -nostdlib and -nodefaultlibs
>   is libgcc.a, a library of internal subroutines which GCC uses to
>   overcome shortcomings of particular machines, or special needs for
>   some languages. (See Interfacing to GCC Output, for more discussion of
>   libgcc.a.) In most cases, you need libgcc.a even when you want to
>   avoid other standard libraries. In other words, when you specify
>   -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs you should usually specify -lgcc as well. This ensures that you have no unresolved references to internal GCC
>   library subroutines.

P.S. The functions `ExitProcess` and `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` are from `kernel32.lib` that **you must include** in linker stream.  You can reduce libraries, but can't omit system and OS libraries.