# How to override c++ startup functions for static binaries?

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc

The `LD_PRELOAD` trick can help for dynamic linking of binaries at runtime, but it will fail for a statically linked binary.

I want to override some c++ startup functions (like changing code for `__libc_start_main`, `__libc_csu_init` and a few others). I was thinking of changing the code directly from `glibc` but I want to be sure that there is no other way to get things worked out.

Is there any other way to override c++ startup functions than to change code from `glibc` and building it again?

Comment: This might be toolchain-specific. Is it GCC/GNU binutils?

Comment: @MSalters yes, I'll be using gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want to exclude, you'll need `-nostartfiles`, `-nodefaultlibs` or `-nostdlib`. You'll then add your own replacements. If your replacement is incomplete (likely), you'd add the original libraries such as `glibc` *after* your own. The linker uses them in the listed order, so your overrides now get preference.

Implictly-linked libraries act as if they appeared first, which is why you need to specifically exclude them and then add them back. See also [g++, static initialization and -nostdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119520/g-static-initialization-and-nostdlib)

Comment: So if I were to override only a few functions, then I could override them and generate a shared object (to link with at compile time). So rest of the functions will be resolved by the linker directly at runtime?

Comment: Well, you still need to link with `glibc` at build time. The runtime linker needs to told which libraries to load, and which functions to find in each library, precisely because the static link did not copy those functions.

Comment: In that case, I'll add those compiler flags then add all the linking files making sure that mine is the first one to override the functions. Is this what you want to say?

Comment: @Rohit: Yes, you got it.